# Sending email through java code using org.eclipse.swt.ole

Tags: java, swt, 64-bit, sendmail, ole

I am trying to send mail through java program using org.eclipse.swt.ole library.
I am using 64bit JVM and 32 bit outlook. When I try to run the program it is showing- "failed to create OLEClientSite". After going through many forums on the internet I think the problem is because of 64bit jvm and 32 bit outlook. I am attaching the code to create the OLEClientSite. If this starts working I can write the program further.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE;    
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleAutomation;  
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleFrame;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class OleTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Email("test@gmail.com","test email", "test");
  }
    public static void Email(String sRecipient, String sSubject, String sReportName)     
{
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        OleFrame frame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);

    // This should start outlook if it is not running yet
        OleClientSite site = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE,   
"Outlook.Application");
        site.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);

        // Now get the outlook application
        OleClientSite site2 = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE,
                "Outlook.Application");
        OleAutomation outlook = new OleAutomation(site2);

    }


}

The error which I am getting is:
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to create Ole Client.     
result = -2147221164
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at OleTest.Email(OleTest.java:22)
    at OleTest.main(OleTest.java:14)
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the problem described in Eclipse bug [361543](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=361543). This is closed as not a problem in Eclipse. It appears that it is not possible to call the 32 bit Outlook from 64 bit SWT (or any 64 bit program).